# Trailing return type for a friend function that accepts class arguments

Tags: c++, friend-function

For the below code :

```
using std::string;

class person
{
private:
    string fname, lname;
    double salary;
public:
    person(string, string, double); // ctor declaration
    ~person(); // dtor declaration
    double operator+(person);
    friend auto salary_burden(person x, person y) -> decltype(x+y); // salary burden of two employees
};
```

I got a red squiggly below `y` inside `decltype` for which Intellisense says `cannot convert to incomplete class "person"`

What is this  all about?

Note : The definitions for the methods including ctors and dtors are in a different translation unit. I guess that is not the cause of the error here.

Comment: What does the compiler say to that? Anyhow, that's abuse of operator overloading, IMHO.

Comment: A couple of contributors here.   `decltype` requires that its operand be of a complete type.  More accurately, since `x + y` involves a function call, that function call should not introduce a temporary.   Since your `operator+()` accepts argument by value, it introduces a temporary (copy of `y` in the expression `x + y`).   Change `operator+()` so calling it does not create a temporary.  Also `operator+()` shouldn't change either of its operands.  Specifically, change it to `double operator+(const person &) const`.

Comment: Even better, don't abuse `operator+()` that way - your approach will cause future maintainers of your class, including yourself, unncessary headaches, since it is counter-intuitive to humans.   Change the friend declaration to `friend double salary_burden(const person &x, const person &y)`   and eliminate the `operator+()` entirely.

Comment: Red squiggly lines is just Intellisense warning about something. That's not the actual compiler. Intellisense is often wrong - compile the code to get the real truth.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : Thanks for the time, I got the point. This was just experimentation btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because even when the operand of `decltype` might be of incomplete type, the same don't hold to subexpressions used to form the prvalue that act as operand of `decltype`

```
decltype(x+y);
```

is equivalent to

```
decltype(operator+(x, y));
```

but `person` is incomplete inside it own definition. You can circumvent this by defining `operator+` as:

```
double operator+(person const&);
```

Comment: Thanks pal, got it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some notes which you may find interesting:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace humans
{
    class person
    {
    private:
        // certainly never write using namespace::thing in header files.
        // if you are going to be using a type, do it in a very confined scope, in a cpp file
        std::string fname, lname;
        double salary;

    public:
        person(std::string, std::string, double); // ctor declaration

        // you neither need or want a destructor for this class.
        // if you define a destructor, you must also define copy & assignment
        // operators. See rule of 5, 3 or none.

        // define a way to see the salary
        double get_salary() const { return salary; }

        // there is no such thing as a person plus a person.
        // avoid nonsensical mathematical abstractions
        // double operator+(person);
    };

    // let's also provide a free function to get_salary, because it can be useful in ADL
    auto get_salary(person const & p) -> decltype(p.get_salary())
    {
        return p.get_salary();
    }


    // salary_burden does not need to be a friend now that we
    // have a way to get the salary. Since there is a free function available
    // in the namespace of person, we could abstract this function a little more!
    auto salary_burden(person const& x, person const& y) -> decltype(get_salary(x) + get_salary(y))
    {
        return get_salary(x) + get_salary(y);
    } 
}

// indeed in c++17 we could also abstract this concept completely...
template<class...Things>
auto salary_burden(Things&&...things)
{
    // here whatever namespace Things is in, this namespace will be
    // searched for a function called get_salary(Thing[&&|const&|&])
    return (get_salary(things) +  ...);
}

namespace non_humans 
{
    struct robot{};
    // note that a robot does not have a get_salary() member
    auto get_salary(robot const&) -> double { return 5; }
}

int main()
{
    auto alice = humans::person("alice", "the programmer", 20000);
    auto bob = humans::person("bob", "the builder", 10000);
    auto robby1 = non_humans::robot();
    auto robby2 = non_humans::robot();
    auto robby3 = non_humans::robot();

    // calls salary_burden(person const& x, person const& y)
    std::cout << salary_burden(alice, bob) << '\n';

    // calls auto salary_burden(Things&&...things)
    std::cout << salary_burden(alice, bob, robby1, robby2, robby3) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments on best practices.  Indeed I agree with each on of those..